# How do I create a navigation bar with buttons and text?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a site I would like to create a bottom navigation bar which has text and buttons. Here is a image[image]

I have tried youtube and google search but they vary from what I desire. Help please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you post the code you've tried so far and then edit the question to include what isn't working as expected? Stack Overflow asks that you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue, preferably in a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#menuFooter {
 
   
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
   
</div>
```